Mouse look/Mouse delta calculation problems
So, I am currently trying to create a mouse look system for a game I am making. Here is my current code:
class InputManager 
{

public:

    bool GetKey(KeyCode key, KeyState state) 
    {
        int vkCode = static_cast<int>(key);
        short result = GetAsyncKeyState(vkCode);

        switch (state) 
        {
        case KeyState::PRESSED:
            return (result & 0x8000) != 0;

        case KeyState::RELEASED:
            return (result & 0x0001) != 0;

        }

        return false;
    }

    bool GetMouseButton(MouseCode key, KeyState state) 
    {
        int vkCode = static_cast<int>(key);
        short result = GetAsyncKeyState(vkCode);

        switch (state) 
        {

        case KeyState::PRESSED:
            return (result & 0x8000) != 0;

        case KeyState::RELEASED:
            return (result & 0x0001) != 0;

        }

        return false;
    }

    Vector2i GetMousePosition() 
    {
        POINT point;

        GetCursorPos(&point);

        return { point.x, point.y };
    }

    Vector2i GetMouseDelta()
    {
        static POINT lastMousePosition = { 0, 0 };
        POINT currentMousePosition;
        GetCursorPos(&currentMousePosition);

        Vector2i delta = {};

        delta.x = currentMousePosition.x - lastMousePosition.x;
        delta.y = currentMousePosition.y - lastMousePosition.y;

        lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;

        return delta;
    }

    void SetMouseMode(const MouseMode& mode)
    {
        ShowCursor((bool)mode);

        mouseMode = mode;
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if (mouseMode == MouseMode::LOCKED && GetKey(KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyState::PRESSED))
            SetMouseMode(MouseMode::FREE);

        if (mouseMode == MouseMode::LOCKED)
        {
            RECT rect;

            GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rect);

            int CenterX = (rect.right - rect.left) / 2;
            int CenterY = (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2;

            SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);

            RECT lockRect = { CenterX, CenterY, CenterX, CenterY };
            ClipCursor(&lockRect);
        }
        else
            ClipCursor(NULL);
    }

    static InputManager& GetInstance() 
    {
        static InputManager instance;

        return instance;
    }

private:

    bool IsCursorInWindow() 
    {
        POINT mousePosition;

        GetCursorPos(&mousePosition);
        ScreenToClient(Window::GetHandle(), &mousePosition);

        RECT clientRect;

        GetClientRect(Window::GetHandle(), &clientRect);

        return PtInRect(&clientRect, mousePosition);
    }

    MouseMode mouseMode = MouseMode::FREE;

    Vector2i mouseDelta = {};
    Vector2i lastPosition = {};

    TimePoint lastUpdate = Clock::now();
    Milliseconds updateInterval{ 16 };

    InputManager() = default;

    InputManager(const InputManager&) = delete;

    void operator=(const InputManager&) = delete;
};

Now, the issue I am currently facing is that instead of the cursor being 'free' for one frame, so that the mouse delta can be calculated properly, the cursor is basically fixed to the center of the screen, and thus the delta calculations result in extremely small values. Also, I cannot seem to move the cursor down or right.
I tried changing the update frequency, asking ChatGPT, changing the update thread, none on which actually worked.

The first thing I see in your code is GetKey, which makes me wonder why is there keyboard handling code in a [mre] demonstrating a problem with mouse movement? The next thing I see is GetMouseButton which leads to a similar question: why button handling code when the issue is mouse movement? Forget your game, and focus on the issue. Don't worry about buttons, keys, or changing the mouse mode. Start in the mode that demonstrates the problem, and get rid of the no-longer needed code; keep it minimal and bare-bones.

A [mre] should reproduce the issue. A class definition by itself has no functionality. (I think the calculation you are concerned about is in Update() but that function is never called in this code snippet.) Your code is missing a simple main/WinMain function to drive the functionality and to show us how you use your class.

This approach is fundamentally flawed, for two reasons: 1 Polling for asynchronous input state will inevitably miss input events. Unreliable input processing destroys any game. It doesn't matter how good it is otherwise, no one will want to play it. 2 Since you are interested in relative mouse movement using the absolute cursor position starts to fail once you hit the screen edges. Here's what you will need to do: Resist the urge to "optimize" your input processing, move it to the UI thread, and switch to Raw Input.

For moving the Cursor, see Using the Keyboard to Move the Cursor. And you have a lastPosition, update it until the delta is enough.
